# mongo capped collection to show new insertion

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to use capped colletion to find database when the insertion happens.but i have some errors in my `.find` method and don't know how to fix it?should i use cursor to do this?

```
url = require("url"),
emitter = require("events").EventEmitter,
assert = require("assert"),

mongo = require("mongodb"),
Cursor = mongo.Cursor;

var uristring = "mongodb://localhost:27017/test"; 
var mongoUrl = url.parse (uristring);


mongo.MongoClient.connect (uristring, function (err, db) { 
        db.collection ("test", function (err,collection) {
        collection.isCapped(function (err, capped) { 
        if (!capped) {
        console.log (collection.collectionName + " is not a capped collection");
        }
        collection.find({},{name:1,_id:0}).sort({$natural: -1}).toArray.stream()(function(err, results) {
            console.log(results);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post what the errors are.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than doing a find(), I think what you want to do is use a [tailable cursor](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/).